# How to use Java HashMap and IdentityHashMap?

Tags: java

I am using HashMap.

Below is example code.

Classes MyKey and MyValue are inhereted from Object in simple way.

Java documentation says for Object and methods hashCode() and equals():

"As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined
by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects.
(This is typically implemented by converting the internal address
of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique
is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)"

"The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating
possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference
values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer
to the same object (x == y has the value true). "

My question is:

Can I trust that HashMap works in my example?
If not what would be right way to put simple objects into map without rewriting methods
hashCode() and equals()?

I am not sure but I have heard that Java may change location and addresss
of user objects during execution of program (Was it GC which may do that?)

If address and hash code of key2 have changed before the line

```
    MyValue v = m.get(key2);
```

then calling m.get(key2) would return wrong value, null?

If this is true then I believe that also IdentityHashMap()
is useless for same reasons.

```
class MyKey
{
  Integer v;
  //<Perhaps more fields>
  MyKey(Integer v) {this.v=v;}
}

class MyValue
{
  String s;
  //<Perhaps more fields>
  MyValue(String s) {this.s = s;}
}


Then some code:

Map<MyKey,MyValue> m = new HashMap<MyKey,MyValue>();

MyKey key1 = new MyKey(5);
MyKey key2 = new MyKey(6);
MyKey key3 = new MyKey(7);


m.put(key1, new MyValue("AAA"));
m.put(key2, new MyValue("BBB"));
m.put(key3, new MyValue("CCC"));

.
.

//Is it sure that I will get value "AAA" here
//if entry with key2 has not been removed from map m?
MyValue v = m.get(key2);
System.out.println("s="+v.s);
```

Comment: To answer the most important question, it is usually very appropriate to use immutable items (Strings, for example) or items with reliably predictable hashcodes (Integers, for example) as the key type in your HashMap.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I trust that HashMap works in my example? If not what would be right way to put simple objects into map without rewriting methods hashCode() and equals()?

You cannot avoid providing a sensible hashCode and equals methods, it is required for HashMap and other Hash collections to work. (with the exception of IdentityHashMap)

> I am not sure but I have heard that Java may change location and addresss of user objects during execution of program (Was it GC which may do that?)

While this is true, it has nothing to do with your main question.

> If address and hash code of key2 have changed before the line

The address and hashCode have nothing to do with one another. If the address changes it doesn't change the hashCode and if you change the hashCode it doesn't change the address.

> If this is true then I believe that also IdentityHashMap() is useless for same reasons.

Even if you assume hashCode is useless, this doesn't affect IndentityHashCode because it doesn't use the `hashCode` or `equals` methods.

---

Objects are basically allocated continuously in memory from the Eden space.  If you run

```
Object[] objects = new Object[20];
for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
    objects[i] = new Object();

Field theUnsafe = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
theUnsafe.setAccessible(true);
Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) theUnsafe.get(null);
for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    int location = unsafe.getInt(objects, Unsafe.ARRAY_OBJECT_BASE_OFFSET + Unsafe.ARRAY_OBJECT_INDEX_SCALE * i);
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(location) + ": hashCode=" + Integer.toHexString(objects[i].hashCode()));
}
```

you might expect them to be continuous if the followed some memory location but they don't

```
eac89d10: hashCode=634e3372
eac89d20: hashCode=2313b44d
eac89d30: hashCode=62a23d38
eac89d40: hashCode=9615a1f
eac89d50: hashCode=233aa44
eac89d60: hashCode=59243f75
eac89d70: hashCode=5ac2480b
eac89d80: hashCode=907f8ba
eac89d90: hashCode=6a5a7ff7
eac89da0: hashCode=5b8767ad
eac89db0: hashCode=50ba0dfc
eac89dc0: hashCode=2198a037
eac89dd0: hashCode=2b3e8c1c
eac89de0: hashCode=17609872
eac89df0: hashCode=46b8705b
eac89e00: hashCode=76d88aa2
eac89e10: hashCode=275cea3
eac89e20: hashCode=4513098
eac89e30: hashCode=6e4d4d5e
eac89e40: hashCode=15128ee5
```

Java has four different way of encoding references in 32-bit and 64-bit, however if your maximum heap size is less than 2 GB it will be a simple 32-bit address as it was when I ran this example.

Comment: I do not understand:

You say:

"The address and hashCode have nothing to do with one another.
If the address changes it doesn't change the hashCode and 
if you change the hashCode it doesn't change the address."

and Java documentation says:

"This (hashCode) is typically implemented by converting the internal address
of the object into an integer"

HashCode and object address do not have nothing to do with one another ???

(..For others to avoid misunderstanding: I am interesting about object instances.
I want that objects equals() only if they are same instances.)a

Comment: The hash code might (or might not) be determined by the _initial_ memory address of the object, but it remains fixed for the lifetime of the object.

Comment: AFAIK, the "internal address" has nothing to do with how it located in memory. see my example.

Comment: Louis, where can I read in some official material that "hash code remains
fixed for the lifetime of the object". It should be saved somewere then.
By the way, I do not understand, why this kind of basic things are not explained
in clear way in Java documentation. How can we write working programs ???

Comment: @heivik the javadoc of hashCode states that it should not change unless the fields used in equals change, the javadoc of Object equals states that it only uses the identity of the object, so no change is possible unless someone implements their own equals and hashcode.

Comment: Jesefx, If they say in that way you are right.
However here we determine basic thing about more complicated things.
For me key, and carefully hidden, knowledge is that hash code is calculated once
when object is created and Object.hashCode() reads that same
value during lifetime of object as people explain here to me.
When I have that information it is very easy to understand that
HashMap (and IdentityHashmap) may do sensible work. Also I could not imagine
that object saves this extra hidden int value,hash code, somewhere!
Of course Immutable,hashCode(),equals() good to know but they easy.

Comment: Even my Java book (Cay S. Horstmann) says in very unclear way about hash code: "That (Object's) hash code is derived from the object's memory address" Well, if objects location changes then that statement is not true if hash code remains constant. 
However the book is very good! Still I would like to see some official information about "only once created hashCode for an object" if someone has that kind of information.

Comment: @heivik A good guarantee that the hashCode() provided by Object is useful can be found in the jls http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2 ____________ Also an Object has depending on the implementation several bytes overhead  so the jvm could store the address the object had on creation as hashcode or it could just return 1, implementation defined. If you read that last sentence you will notice that the computation of hashcode is implementation defined only the guarantees of the spec and the javadoc have to be met, so no guarantee about how often it is computed.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I trust that HashMap works in my example? If not what would be right way to put simple objects into map without rewriting methods hashCode() and equals()?

Your example does not provide hashCode or equals, so it will use the defaults.
The dafaults work with the object identity, which means o.equals(o2) will be true only if o and o2 refer to the same object.

```
 MyKey m = new MyKey(1);
 MyKey m2 = new MyKey(1);
 MyKey m3 = m;

 map.put(m,...);
 map.get(m);//works
 map.get(m2); //different object
 map.get(m3);//works same object
```

> I am not sure but I have heard that Java may change location and addresss of user objects during execution of program (Was it GC which may do that?)

The address of an object is not relevant, while the default hashCode might use it this happens only once for each object and then stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the default hashcode of an object does not change after it is constructed so IdentityHashMap is not useless.  Java may move objects around in memory but it doesn't change their identity hash code.

Secondly, if you don't define your own `equals()` method, then every object you construct will be not `equals()` to every other.  This means if you want to use them as keys in a HashMap (or IdentityHashMap) you'll only be able to retrieve them by using the original object.

For example:

```
MyKey key = new MyKey(5);
m.put(key, value);
...
MyKey newKey = new MyKey(5);
m.get(newKey); // Will not find the value
```

As `newKey` and `key` are different objects, they are not `==`. This is why you are recommended to override `equals()` (and `hashcode()`) for you objects.

A `HashMap` still works if you don't override `equals()` and `hashcode()` on your objects but it will generally not do what you want - in this case, it becomes equivalent to `IdentityHashMap`